# Making A Sprite Rotate To A Specific Angle XNA 4.0

Tags: xna-4.0, rotation

I have a game that the character spins when you press either of the triggers on the xbox remote. Here's the code.

```
if (gamepadState.IsButtonDown(Buttons.RightTrigger))
        RotationAngle += spinSpeed;

if (gamepadState.IsButtonDown(Buttons.LeftTrigger))
        RotationAngle -= spinSpeed;
```

what i want to happen is when neither of the triggers are being pressed he rotates back to a rotation angle of 0. I know How to make him go back to 0 when neither triggers are pulled but its too abrupt. How can i make the sprite actually rotate back to an angle of 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private bool isTurning;

public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    isTurning = false;
    if (gamepadState.IsButtonDown(Buttons.RightTrigger))
    {
        RotationAngle += spinSpeed;
        isTurning = true;
    }

    if (gamepadState.IsButtonDown(Buttons.LeftTrigger))
    {
        RotationAngle -= spinSpeed;
        isTurning = true;
    }

    if (!isTurning && RotationAngle != 0)
    {
        if (RotationAngle > 0)
        {
            RotationAngle -= spinSpeed;
            if (RotationAngle < 0)
                RotationAngle = 0;
        }
        else if (RotationAngle < 0)
        {
            RotationAngle += spinSpeed;
            if (RotationAngle > 0)
                RotationAngle = 0;
        }
    }
}
```